# Unable to send TX using arch3.js

Tags: archway-network

After the Archway CLI V2 update, and the Archway V4.0.0 patch, I started encountering an error when sending TXs (reading contract functions works fine).

This is the error I am currently getting :

```
Error: Error when broadcasting tx DBBC8D3AD1923DE02D019A105879FBEFDFC76C07CB55084CDCBF0A3665C8ADAE at height 1688875. Code: 11; Raw log: out of gas in location: WriteFlat; gasWanted: 182764, gasUsed: 184087: out of gas
```

This happens both using frontend code (with keplr plugin), and backend standard js code (using a DirectSecp256k1HdWallet invocation)